# No se suben todos los archivos a Github al hacer commit

Tags: git, github, git-push

Me surge la siguiente duda:

Estoy trabajando con un proyecto en PHP y pesa alrededor de 1.5 GB. Y además de esto contiene un poco más de 5000 archivos.

Al hacer el **git add .** y el **git commit -m** "Comentarios del commit" no ocurre ningún problema, de echo tampoco lo hay cuando realizo el **git push origin master**, pero al momento de abrir github me percato de que no están todos los archivos que tengo en mi proyecto de manera local.

¿Alguna idea del por que sucede esto?

Comment: puedes tener algunos ignorados ya sea en tu `.gitignore` en la raíz, o bien en un `.gitignore` de un subdirectorio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si estas utilizando algun framework normalmente estos trae un archivo llamado `.gitignore` que lo hace es contener una serie de nombres tanto de archivos como de carpetas, el git viene he ignora estos archivos. Con que fin? simplemente es por eso, para no subir cosas que no sean necesarias, como son los modulos q pueden ser descargados con una linea de comando, esos modulos que has agregado se guardan en un archivo `package.json` tambien se utiliza para ignorar archivos de conexion a la base de datos.

puede leer mas sobre `.gitignore` [Aqui](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: Gracias, no trabajo con un framework pero si realice la integración de Chamilo y tenia su propio archivo .gitignore además del que yo ya había agregado con anterioridad. Muchas gracias por el aporte.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que eso suceda es porque esta trabajando en un directorio dentro del proyecto, por lo tanto al hacer el `git add` y el `git commit -m ""` no va a tomar todos los cambios realizados en todo el poyecto. En ese caso lo que debe hacer es ubicarse en la raiz del proyecto.

Comment: Puede ser por el tema de las quotas de GitHub? https://help.github.com/en/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota